# Error while creating MySql event scheduling for a specific period of time everyday with an interval of i hour

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-event

Error while creating MySql event scheduling for a specific period of time everyday with an interval of 1 hour.

My code are

```
CREATE EVENT your_event ON SCHEDULE 
   EVERY 30 MINUTE
   STARTS '2013-10-01 10:00:00'
DO
  IF time(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) between time('10:00:00') and time('18:00:00')
  then
        INSERT INTO andrew (name) values ('test')
  end if
```

and the error is:

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'end if' at line 8**

Comment: You missed the query terminator `;` in the end of the `INSERT` and `END IF` statements

Comment: Even after giving end the statement with ;, problem were same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;)

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE EVENT your_event ON SCHEDULE 
   EVERY 30 MINUTE
   STARTS '2013-10-01 10:00:00'
DO
IF time(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN time('10:00:00') AND time('18:00:00') THEN
    INSERT INTO andrew (name) VALUES ('test');
END IF $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! You did it... Since morning I was googling for same but finally you did it... Thanks again... Its now working fine.

Comment: This query is running successfully but when i check the event list, no any event were created

Comment: I've tried this query, and it really created a event. :(

Comment: Yes last I tried it on workbench i worked fine. There was problem with old version of XAMPP.